# Can a Spring Cloud Stream in Spring Cloud Data Flow be triggered?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

We have a scenario wherein we have to process each entry of data in a database table. But this should be user triggered when they will decide to start the processing.

We are happy with the stream processing since we could decouple each process steps into stream applications and scale them as necessary. Other option we have is to just make it a task with batch job.

If we are to do this via stream, we are thinking of an approach to have an http source (to get the trigger) -> jdbc source/processor (to retrieve each record) -> app processor (to process each record) -> jdbc sink (to save to db)

Is there an elegant solution or other way to do this via spring cloud stream and spring cloud data flow?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle this via stream, then you can POST `http` source the message every time you want to trigger explicitly by the user. Or, if you want to configure something like a fixed-delay or cron trigger you can make use of OOTB `trigger` source [app](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/trigger/tree/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-trigger)

If this can be handled via task, then Spring Data Flow GUI/Shell provides `task launch` option where user can trigger the `task execution`.